Wondering whether complex square root satisfies a kind of sub-additivity
I'm wondering whether a pretty elementary inequality holds. Let $z,w$ be complex numbers in the right half-plane, i.e. having real parts $>0$. Is it always true that
$$|z^{1/2} - w^{1/2}| \leq |z - w|^{1/2}?$$
Here I'm taking the principle square root (branch cut negative reals). When $z,w$ are real, the inequality follows from the sub-additivity property of the square-root. But I'm having trouble proving the general version or finding a counter-example.
Thanks for any help!

If $z$ and $w$ are in the right half-plane and $\sqrt{\cdot}$ denotes the principal branch of the square root then
$$
 |\sqrt z + \sqrt w|^2 = |z| + |w| + 2 \operatorname{Re}(\sqrt { z} \cdot \overline{\sqrt{ w}}) > |z| + |w| \ge |z-w|
$$
because both $\sqrt z$ and $ \overline{\sqrt{ w}}$ have an argument in the range $(-\pi/4, \pi/4)$, so that their product has a positive real part. It follows that
$$
 |\sqrt z - \sqrt w| = \frac{|z-w|}{|\sqrt z + \sqrt w|} \le \sqrt{|z-w|} \, .
$$
The inequality is strict unless $z=w$.

Adding a different bound here which is more restrictive when $z-w$ is small, since Martin answered my main question. Notice $$|z^{\frac 1 2} - w^{\frac 1 2}| |z^{\frac 1 2} + w^{\frac 1 2}| = |z - w|.$$ Now $$|z^{\frac 1 2} + w^{\frac 1 2}| = |z|^{\frac 1 2}|1 + z^{-\frac 1 2}w^{\frac 1 2}|.$$ Since $z,w$ are in the right half-plane, so is $z^{-\frac 1 2}w^{\frac 1 2}$. It follows that $|z^{\frac 1 2} + w^{\frac 1 2}| > |z|^{1/2}$. So
$$|z^{\frac 1 2} - w^{\frac 1 2}|<|z|^{-\frac 1 2}|z - w|.$$
